# Вопрос по C в Obj-C

Tags: objective-c

В старом тесте по Obj-C встретил вопрос по использованию С-типов.
Что из перечесленного не используется в Обжектив-С?

- Битовые поля
- Составные литералы
- Структуры
- C-массивы
- Поддержка зависит от компилятора

Ответ может содержать более одного варианта. Знаю что сейчас обжси уже поддерживает литералы, но когда был писан этот тест еще точно не поддерживал. Просьба дополнить ответ если возможно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эм, ну вообще-то любой валидный Си код - приемлим в objective-c.